# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Hey Guys i just want to share this with you in case you get the same error :

```
pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/$(whoami)/Library/Python/3.7/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just solved this problem by updating pip. Like this:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

remove all python folders, and reference found here :

- /usr/local/bin/
- /usr/local/lib
- /usr/local/Cellar/
- /Users/$(whoami)/Library/Python/
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/ (Only if it exists !! for me it doesnt)

Then run :

```
brew install python3
```